# Couldn't insert new article. Reason: %!(EXTRA sqlite3.Error=no such table: articles) Beego

Tags: go, beego

Getting this error `Couldn't insert new article. Reason: %!(EXTRA sqlite3.Error=no such table: articles` when trying to add an article to table articles.

\
     **models.go**

```
package models

type Article struct {
    Id     int    `form:"-"`
    Name   string `form:"name,text,name:" valid:"MinSize(5);MaxSize(20)"`
    Client string `form:"client,text,client:"`
    Url    string `form:"url,text,url:"`
}

func (a *Article) TableName() string {
    return "articles"
}
```

\
    **part of my Add function**

```
if err == orm.ErrNoRows || err == orm.ErrMissPK {
     beego.Debug("No article found matching details supplied. Attempting to insert article: ", article)
     id, err := o.Insert(&article)
     if err == nil {
         msg := fmt.Sprintf("Article inserted with id:", id)
         beego.Debug(msg)
         flash.Notice(msg)
         flash.Store(&manage.Controller)
      } else {
         msg := fmt.Sprintf("Couldn't insert new article. Reason: ", err)
         beego.Debug(msg)
         flash.Error(msg)
         flash.Store(&manage.Controller)
      }
} else {
     beego.Debug("Article found matching details supplied. Cannot insert")
}
```

Please assist. I don't know what am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, *do* you have a table called `articles`?

Comment: I have a database called orm_test.db; orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "sqlite3", "database/orm_test.db")

Comment: Not sure if I need to Sync my database..

Comment: Whenever you get "%!(EXTRA" from `fmt` please go and fix your broken format string (or use `Print`/`Println` instead of `Printf` if you don't want a format string).

Comment: @Dave, is that the solution to the question. Please read the question very well

Comment: @OladayoOyelade, it's a *comment*, not an *answer*. Please learn the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, I need to Sync my database(similar with Django >> `python manage.py makemigrations/migrate`). So I edited my main function inside main.go to:

```
func main() {
    err := orm.RunSyncdb("default", false, false)
    if err != nil {
        beego.Error(err)
    }
    beego.Run()
}
```

This works for me.